# wpf caliburn ComboBox OnSelectionChanged Event Exception

Tags: wpf, exception, mvvm, combobox, caliburn

I am trying to teach myself WPF, MVVM with Caliburn Micro. All going well so far but I have an issue trying to get an Event to fire in my ViewModel when a comboBox in my view has it's selection changed.

This is the top of my view (in Xaml):

```
<Window x:Class="Translator.Views.TranslatorView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Translator.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=model:TranslatorViewModel}"
    Title="Translator" Height="269.301" Width="1030.263"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
```

This is my Xaml for my ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Name="StoreCombo" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Height="25"     SelectedValue="{Binding Type}" 
cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [StoreSelectionChanged]"
cal:Action.Target="{Binding ElementName=StoreCombo, Path=DataContext}">
</ComboBox>
```

And this is my Event in my ViewModel:

```
public void StoreSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
}
```

However I get this exception when running the application and changing the selection:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WindowsBase.dll 
Additional information: No target found for method StoreSelectionChanged.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

I have tried to google this but so far, I can't figure out what I need to do.

Can anyone help me at all?

Many thanks

Comment: Try to get rid of method arguments if you don't need them. Moreover, you are not passing any arguments to the method. Change it to this `public void StoreSelectionChanged()` and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That fixes it and the event fires. But in my event I need to know the comboboxes current selected item. How can I do this without sending the combobox as the "sender"? thanks

Comment: Ideally you should bind `SelectedItem` of ComboBox to some property in ViewModel instead of handling `SelectionChanged` event. I just saw you already have `SelectedValue` bound then why you need selected item? You can write your code in its property setter.

Comment: Of course! :-) Tried that and it works. Thanks very much

Comment: Great I have converted this into an answer. So that it can be helpful for others as well. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
  <ComboBox Name="StoreCombo" SelectedValue="{Binding Type}" 
         cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [StoreSelectionChanged]"
         cal:Action.Target="{Binding ElementName=StoreCombo, Path=DataContext}">
  </ComboBox>
```

(1) : Target is already it's DataContext , so just **remove** this line all together.

```
    cal:Action.Target="{Binding ElementName=StoreCombo, Path=DataContext}"
```

(2) [Caliburn Cheat Sheet](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Cheat%20Sheet&referringTitle=Documentation) , If you **don't need** the (Sender ,EventArgs)

```
   cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action StoreSelectionChanged]"
```

(2.1) If you want **eventargs** :

```
   cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action StoreSelectionChanged($eventArgs)]"
```

(2.2) If you want **sender** and **eventargs**

```
   cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action StoreSelectionChanged($this,$eventArgs)]"
```

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of method parameters in method since you are not passing any arguments to the method.

Change it to this:

```
public void StoreSelectionChanged()
{
}
```

---

Also, on side note since you already have **`SelectedValue`** bind to property in ViewModel, you don't need this event. Put the code in property setter of SelectedValue.